# How to add BluetoothDevice to paired( bonded ) list and remove deve form this list?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it posible add ble device to paired(Bonded) list with android api level 18?

What I mean:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Is it posible remove BluetoothDevice form Andorid os BondedDevices list automaticaly from code?

Comment: Please check your spelling, this question is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the Android OS can put a `BluetoothDevice` in/out of this list when bond state of this device will change.
It is possible to initiate the bonding process from the Android OS side in two ways:

1. Start interacting with the peripheral and read/write the characteristic that needs encryption-the bonding process will get started automatically by the system once the peripheral will respond with status `INSUFFICIENT_AUTH`
2. Call the `BluetoothDevice` function `public boolean createBond()`. This function is officially from the API 19 but as you can see in [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r1/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#712) it was available before but hidden. It is possible to call it via reflection

To remove the `BluetoothDevice` from the list one may call another hidden function `public boolean removeBond()`. Again reflection is needed as this function is not visible even on the newest API.

Keep in mind that Low Energy bonding is a subject to bugs especially on older Android versions.